# how to create a large database with Ansible

Tags: mysql, linux, ansible

Suppose you have a sql-file database.sql, which creates the database schema, the table within it and some initial filling. Normally, I can use ansible to make this database by:

```
---

- name: copy database.sql to server
  template: src=database.sql dest=/tmp/database.sql owner=root group=root

- name: sql the thing into MySQL
  command: mysql "-u root -p{{ mysql_root_password }} < /tmp/database.sql"

- name: remove the sql file from the server
  command: rm -f /tmp/database.sql
```

and this does exactly what it says. But when database.sql is large (perhaps 2 TByte) you really don't want the copying action first. Are there ways to refer to database.sql as a file on the ansible-master server (where we push it from) such that you can do a mysql -u root@master -p... < "local file" such that the copy action isn't needed anymore ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whatever you do, data must flow from where it is to the database server. Note that in your example you should have used `copy` instead of `template` : templates are being parsed by Jinja, and parsing big files is very costly.

That being said, you might want to use `local_action` and remotely feed your mysql server :

```
- name: feed database.sql to server
  local_action: shell mysql -u root -p{{ mysql_root_password }} -h {{ ansible_default_ipv4 }} < /tmp/database.sql
```

This would run the command locally and should work if :

- your DB dump is in `/tmp/database.sql` on the localmachine
- `/tmp/database.sql` contains database creation statements
- you can remotely connect to your mysql server (hint: check rights + bind_address)

To make things a bit cleaner, you could use the `mysql_db` module :

```
- name: feed database.sql to server
  local_action: mysql_db login_user=root login_password={{ mysql_root_password }} login_host={{ ansible_default_ipv4 }} name={{ db_name }} state=import target=/tmp/database.sql
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For centos / debian the mysql_db works fine. There seems to be a mismatch in packages when I install ansible on RHEL 6 via epel. To begin with, the jinja version on epel is not the one ansible is using here (I did have to download a jinja2 python rpm manually). Same problem wih mysql_db. Then the python_mysqldb module needed for that is not the one on epel.

Comment: I think it is in the base repos (yum install MySQL-python). For Jinja2, this is weird since there is a `Requires: python-jinja2` in the RPM spec file (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/packaging/rpm/ansible.spec). However, I'm not using CentOS so I don't really know much on this, sorry :(